# Can't add tag while editing someone's question

Tags: support, tags, edits

I tried replacing the `jsx` tag with the `react-jsx` tag in this question:

[VSCode Prettier reformat adds {" "} when adding new line between html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807870/vscode-prettier-reformat-adds-when-adding-new-line-between-html-tags)

The new tag never got added. I tried multiple times to add the tag in following edits, but the tag never got added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag [react-jsx] is a *synonym* of [reactjs]; you can see this on the [Tag Synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/reactjs/synonyms). So basically you're adding the same tag twice, and the system picks one: the 'master' tag, which is [reactjs].

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. There was absolutely no way to determine that from the UI. You just have to *know* somehow that it's a synonym (and that the concept of synonyms even exists).